# Как расширить раздел с Kali Linux?

Tags: linux, kali-linux, диск, раздел, разметка-диска

Объясните, плиз, на пальцах.
Имею диск с **4** разделами: 1)Резерв 2)Шиндовс 3)Файлы помойка 4)**Kali Linux и рядом неразмеченная** область для 4 раздела. 
Из 16 гб сделать 32 гб раздел с линуксом

Не шарю ни в каких там "lvm lva" и всё такое, а линукс сбивать не хочется, да и таблицу разделов тоже.

На скриншотах **помечены разделы для объединения**.[image: скрин]

[image: скрин 2]

Comment: Просто измените размер /dev/sda5 растянув его на свободное пространство.

Comment: Как? Ничего не "растягивается", 16 гигов максимум, а sda4 можно сжать до 16

Comment: Покажите скриншот, как у вас ничего не растягивается

Comment: добавил скрин, если вы про это

Comment: Если этот раздел примонтирован, то сперва отмонтируйте его, а уже потом изменяйте размер

Comment: umount: /: target is busy. Он же занят сейчас линуксом

Comment: Если вы загрузились с этого раздела, то системный раздел отмонтировать нельзя. Загрузитесь с LiveCD/LiveUSB, а уже потом изменяйте размер

Comment: Лол только windows сейчас под рукой, никак не сделать?

Comment: Скачать образ любого линукса из интернета и записать на любую флешку, чтобы под рукой был не только windows. Вообще, иметь флешку с линуксом никогда не помешает

Comment: по-другому никак?

Comment: Может, какое-нибудь windows-приложение тоже умеет перемещать разделы, но сам я таких не знаю (у меня всегда есть флешка с убунтой и мне норм)

Comment: На виндовс есть старый добрый `партишн меджик`.

Comment: *по-другому никак?* — теоретически можно и «по-другому». но этот теоретический путь сложнее предложенного (загрузка с временного носителя) раз эдак примерно в тысячу. ну, может, в пятьсот. с вероятностью «всё запороть к чертям», близкой к единице.